# $(this).closest(("select[name*='FIELD2']") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this form:

```
<div id="div_id_form-0-FIELD1" class="form-group">
  <label for="id_form-0-FIELD1" class="control-label col-sm-2">
    Amount Type
  </label>
  <div class="controls col-sm-3">
    <select class="select form-control" id="id_form-0-FIELD1" name="form-0-FIELD1">
      <option value="">---------</option>
      <option value="d" selected="selected">Dollars</option>
      <option value="p">Percent of</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_form-0-FIELD2" class="form-group">
  <label for="id_form-0-FIELD2" class="control-label col-sm-2">
    Deduct from total
  </label>
  <div class="controls col-sm-3">
    <select class="select form-control" id="id_form-0-FIELD2" name="form-0-FIELD2">
      <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
      <option value="g">Gross Pay</option>
      <option value="n">Net Pay</option>
      <option value="h">Hourly Rate</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have`FIELD1` in `($this)`, I want to get `FIELD2`. This is not getting it for me:

```
$(this).closest(("select[name*='FIELD2']")
```

Comment: `.closest` traverses the **ancestors** of a node. It looks like you want to get the *descendant* of a *sibling* of the node (or the descendant of a sibling of an ancestor).

Comment: `.closest` searches _up_ the DOM tree. `FIELD1` is not inside `FIELD2`.

Comment: Use `.next()`, `.siblings()`, or `.nextAll()`, depending on the relationship between the elements in the DOM.

Comment: use .find() instead because .closest() searched up while find searches in it's children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.next()` method, like so:

```
$(this)
    .closest("div.form-group")
    .next("div.form-group")
         .find("select[name*='FIELD2']");
```